# How to benefit the auditing infra of spring data mongo?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

Unlike spring data jpa I could not find the **@EntitListeners** annotation in spring data mongo which I could use along with @Document annotation on models for auditing purpose.

Early guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are LifeCycle Events like in JPA also for MongoDB.

Have a look at the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events